# How to include this node_module's .html asset in webpack?

Tags: javascript, webpack, electron

I am using the package `electron-notifications` and it relies on a `.html` and `.css` file in its `assets` folder. This assets folder is not included in webpack (1.14.0) though.

I know I should not add a module as an entry point. I have come across a concept called code splitting, but I'm not clear on how that works and if that is what I need to be looking into further. Any advice you can give would be greatly appreciated.

**webpack.config.production.js**

```
import path from 'path';
import webpack from 'webpack';
import validate from 'webpack-validator';
import ExtractTextPlugin from 'extract-text-webpack-plugin';
import merge from 'webpack-merge';
import HtmlWebpackPlugin from 'html-webpack-plugin';
import BabiliPlugin from 'babili-webpack-plugin';
import baseConfig from './webpack.config.base';

export default validate(merge(baseConfig, {

  devtool: 'inline-source-map',

  entry: [
    'babel-polyfill',
    './app/index'
  ],

  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'app/dist'),
    publicPath: '../dist/'
  },

  module: {
    loaders: [

      // Extract all .global.css to style.css as is
      {
        test: /\.global\.css$/,
        //  loaders: [
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract(
          'style-loader',
          'css-loader?sourceMap'
        )
        // ]
      },

      // Pipe other styles through css modules and append to style.css
      {
        test: /^((?!\.global).)*\.css$/,
        //  loaders: [
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract(
          'style-loader',
          'css-loader?modules&importLoaders=1&localIdentName=[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]'
        )
      },

      // Fonts
      { test: /\.woff(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: 'url?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff' },
      { test: /\.woff2(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: 'url?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff' },
      { test: /\.ttf(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: 'url?limit=10000&mimetype=application/octet-stream' },
      { test: /\.eot(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: 'file' },
      { test: /\.svg(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: 'url?limit=10000&mimetype=image/svg+xml' },
      // Images
      {
        test: /\.(?:ico|gif|png|jpg|jpeg|webp)$/,
        loader: 'url-loader'
      }
    ]
  },

  plugins: [
    // https://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#occurrenceorderplugin
    // https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/864
    new webpack.optimize.OccurrenceOrderPlugin(),

    // NODE_ENV should be production so that modules do not perform certain development checks
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production')
    }),
    new BabiliPlugin(),
    new ExtractTextPlugin('style.css', { allChunks: true }),

    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      filename: '../app.html',
      template: 'app/app.html',
      inject: false
    })
  ],

  // https://github.com/chentsulin/webpack-target-electron-renderer#how-this-module-works
  target: 'electron-renderer'
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want that packages' CSS to be recognised by the webpack, you just add it to the style's(CSS's) loader block, as an `include` attribute along with "test" and "loader". In the include attribute point it to the node_modules/electron_notification path.

HTML of that package need not be included, since your Single Page Application, has it's own HTML, if needed try to replicate the class names there. But I doubt if you need to do that.

Comment: This particular package creates its own window, so the HTML is needed   unfortunately.

Comment: Do you mean adds it's own div? I don't understand when you say creates it's own window?

Comment: I'm using Electron. This package creates additional browserWindows to show the notifications. Entire new windows with their own HTML and CSS entirely separate form my application except for parameters passed in.

Comment: I haven't seen BrowserWindows before. So my help ends with helping you include the CSS bit..!